# ssh-keygen -s outputs half of a created key and fails

Tags: ssh, bash, certificate

So I'm running ssh-keygen to sign a user certificate.

The command I'm using looks like this:

```
ssh-keygen -s ${CERTIFICATE} -I ${GITHUB_USERNAME} -n ${AUTH_PRINCIPAL} -V +${LEASE_TIME} -z ${SERIAL} -O source-address=${ALLOWED_CIDR} ${WORK_DIR}/${GITHUB_USERNAME}.pub
```

This works currently in a different bash script that I'm working from.

What happens is this will run and will print most of a key to stdout but not end up writing to the `-cert.pub` file that it's meant to.

Adding some `-vvv` to the command does not increase its output so I'm not able to find out what's going on.

Any ideas?